# how to use ScrollListener in SherlockListFragment?

Tags: android, android-listfragment, onscrolllistener

i have done in gridView ScrollListener but how to do in SherlockListFragment 
i want to create app like gmail mail list 
its refresh like Gmail ActionbarPullToRefresh and load more mail as gmail app

please help me thanks in advance

```
protected GridView  gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

gridView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if (!loading
                    && load(firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount,
                            totalItemCount)) {
                loading = true;

                loadMore();
            }
        }
    });
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Note: its ListFragment so i don't want to do like ListView  listview= (Listview) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

Comment: Use pulltoRefresh library project.

Comment: i have already  use ActionbarPullToRefresh Lib

Comment: ^(?:(?:31(/)(?:0[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(/)(?:0[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:19|20)\d{2})$|^(?:29(/)02\3(?:(?:(?:(?:19|20))(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:19|20)\d{2})$